# "Pulling Up" a Function at a Specific Point in an Interval

Tags: functions

Given a function $f(x)$ that is continuous, constructed so that $f(x) \geq 0$ and has finitely many points in between an interval $[a,b]$, is there a way to "pull up" a function at a point $c$ in $[a,b]$, so that at $c$, the function would be at its highest point in $[a,b]$ and on either side it decreases (but not become negative). The zeroes, however, should remain zeros. We are going to assume $c$ is not at $a$, $b$, or any zeroes of $f(x)$. Here is an example $f(x)$ on the interval $[95,107]$ (note the root at $101$). Let's say $c$ should be $99$:
[image]

Here is what I want the "pulled up function to look like:
[image]

Comment: Your initial function already had a maximum at $x=99$ - did you intend to 'pull up' at a different value?

Comment: @tomi That was just an example. It could be any value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the pdf of the Normal distribution $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 }$. If $\sigma$ is small enough this is pretty much zero everywhere except for the values close to $x=\mu$.

If your required 'pull up' point is at $x=c$ then let $g(x)=k e^{ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-c}{\sigma}\right)^2 }+1$

This function is close to 1 everywhere except near $x=c$ where it takes the value $k$.

Take your old function $f(x)$ and create a new function $f'(x)=f(x)g(x)$

For most points you will find $f'(x)=f(x)$ but at $x=c$ you will have $f'(x)=kf(x)$.

You can adapt your values of $k$ and $\sigma$ to increase the height at point at $x=c$ and to narrow the effect of the 'pull up'

Comment: Excellent answer! This is what I want.